# $\det\left(I + A^TA^{-1}\right) = 2\left(1 + \operatorname{tr}\left(A^TA^{-1}\right)\right)$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Let $A$ be an invertible $3\times3$ matrix with complex values. Prove that:
$$\det\left(I + A^TA^{-1}\right) = 2\left(1 + \operatorname{tr}\left(A^TA^{-1}\right)\right)$$

I've tried to solve this problem with characteristic polynomial but in the end I got stuck in an expression involvind Newton's identities regarding that polynomial. I cannot relate $A^TA^{-1}$ with characteristic polynomial.

Comment: By $(\cdot )^T$ I assume you mean the Hermitian transpose?

Comment: No, I believe the OP means ordinary transpose.

Comment: First compute $det(A^tA^{-1})$ then use Ted Shifrin's hint.

Comment: It is ordinary transpose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $B = A^T A^{-1}$, we have $\det(B) = 1$.  Moreover, $1$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ because $B - I = (A^T - A) A^{-1}$, $A^T - A$ is antisymmetric, and any antisymmetric matrix in odd dimensions must be singular.  If the eigenvalues of $B$ are $1, \lambda, 1/\lambda$, then $\text{tr}(B) = 1 + \lambda + 1/\lambda$
and $\det(I+B) = 2 (1 + \lambda) (1 + 1/\lambda) = 4 + 2 \lambda + 2/\lambda$.

Comment: Indeed, well done, +1!

Comment: Thank you! Very smart solution :)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Every complex matrix can be put in upper-triangular form. Try it for any diagonal matrix $A$ first.

Comment: But although $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are put in upper-triangular form by the same $S$, $A^T$ is not.  So it's not clear to me how to get the general case from that.

Comment: Surely some aspect of $3 \times 3$ must play into this?

Comment: Indeed: for $4 \times 4$ matrices there is no linear dependence between $\det(I+A^T A^{-1})$, $\text{tr}(A^T A^{-1})$ and $1$.

Comment: Ah, @RobertIsrael, I was in too much of a hurry. You are, as usual, quite correct. :) But what if we put $A^\top A^{-1}$ in upper-triangular form?

Comment: You just need to write $A^tA^{-1}=RTR^{-1}$(T is triangular) and compute $\det(A^tA^{-1})$.

Comment: $det(A^TA^{-1})$ = 1

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=A^TA^{-1}$. Then
$$
\operatorname{tr}(S^{-1})
=\operatorname{tr}\left((S^{-1})^T\right)
=\operatorname{tr}(A^{-1}A^T)
=\operatorname{tr}(A^TA^{-1})
=\operatorname{tr}(S).
$$
and $\det(S)=1$. Therefore the characteristic polynomial of $S$ is
$$
\begin{aligned}
p(x)
&=x^3-\operatorname{tr}(S)x^2+\det(S)\operatorname{tr}(S^{-1})x-\det(S)\\
&=x^3-\operatorname{tr}(S)x^2+\operatorname{tr}(S)x-1.
\end{aligned}
$$
Consequently, $\det(I+S)=-p(-1)=2\left(1+\operatorname{tr}(S)\right)$.