# Prove that $\left(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\|a_i\right\|_2^2 \right) < \det(I_m + AA^*) , A \in M_{m,n}$ and $a_i$ is $i$th column of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra

- Prove the following inequality is true $$\left(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\|a_i\right\|_2^2 \right) < \det(I_m + AA^*) \ ,$$

in which $A \in M_{m,n}$ and $a_i$ corresponds to the $i$th column of $A$.

- Also, prove that if $A$ is rank $1$ matrix, then the above inequality is an equality.

---

I have tested this numerically (e.g., MATLAB) and it seems to be true. However, I am not sure how to prove it mathematically yet. Any suggestions and help will be highly appreciated.

I think it is closely related to this one: [$\det\left(I + A^TA^{-1}\right) = 2\left(1 + \operatorname{tr}\left(A^TA^{-1}\right)\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085020/det-lefti-ata-1-right-2-left1-operatornametr-leftata-1-ri) , but not same.

Comment: Besides numerical experiments, why do you believe that it should be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M$ be a positive semi-definite matrix of size $m\times m$ and let $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_m$ be its eigenvalues. Then

$$ \det(I_m+M)
= \prod_{k=1}^{m} (1 + \lambda_k)
\geq 1+\sum_{k=1}^{m} \lambda_k
= 1+\operatorname{tr}(M). $$

Now the result follows by noticing that $\operatorname{tr}(AA^*) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \lvert a_{ij} \rvert^2$.

Comment: Thank you. This looks promising. Just out of curiosity, is this some standard inequality?